# Изменить значение регистра во время выполнения программы?

Tags: c++, linux, c, gdb

Видел, как с помощью gdb, ставят брекпоинт, меняют значение регистра, продолжают выполнение, результат изменился. То есть так можно любую программу изменить? Какие есть хорошие дисассемблеры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После перезапуска программы все регистры теряются. Так что скорее всего программа сохранила свой результат где в файл/реестр, а потом прочитала.

Так работать можно практически с любой программой. Некоторые программы могут просто активно сопротивляться (например, так делал раньше скайп и делают многие игры).

gdb вполне хорошая штука, если научится пользоваться. Для начала прочитать что то вида [статьи с хабра](https://habr.com/ru/post/491534/).

Из дизассемблеров можно отметить классику - [IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware/) - сейчас есть бесплатные версии, [OllyDbg](https://www.ollydbg.de/) - старая классика и под линукс есть [radare2](https://rada.re/n/) - очень интересная разработка, хотя и требует (как и любой дизассемблер) много знаний.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас нашел еще защиту типа канарейка.

Comment: канарейка это от переполнения стека/массива. А есть защиты, которые шифруют код, замеряют время выполнения отдельных кусков и если оно сильно отличается - тревога.